# SQL Server : divide by zero error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have searched the forums and found several responses on this topic but as I am new to SQL I'm not getting it.

I created a TSQL query that when run returns "Divide by zero error". This is because I am dividing one column by another and there is a zero in one of the records. Ok, I got that part but I can't make heads or tails of the posts explaining how to resolve the issue.

```
SELECT 
    f.Sales_Rep1 AS 'Sales Rep'
    , SUM(CAST(f.Other1_Revenue + f.Other2_Revenue AS FLOAT)) AS 'MRR'
    , CW.MRR_Goal AS 'MRR Goal'
    , SUM((f.Other1_Revenue + f.Other2_Revenue)/(CW.MRR_Goal)) AS 'Total'
    , SUM(CAST(f.Product_Revenue + f.Service_Revenue AS FLOAT)) AS 'NRR'
    , CW.NRR_Goal AS 'NRR Goal'
    , (cw.MRR_Goal + cw.NRR_Goal)AS 'Total Goal'
FROM 
    dbo.v_rpt_Opportunity AS f 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.v_memberpickerlist AS m ON f.Sales_Rep1 = m.Member_ID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.CW_SalesGoals AS CW ON CW.Sales_Rep = f.Sales_Rep1
WHERE 
    (f.Expected_Close_Date >= DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) 
    AND (m.activestatus = 'active') AND (f.Status = 'Won') 
    OR (f.Expected_Close_Date >= DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) 
    AND (m.activestatus = 'active') 
    AND (f.Status LIKE '%submitted%')
GROUP BY 
    f.Sales_Rep1, CW.MRR_Goal, CW.NRR_Goal, 
    f.Other1_Revenue, f.Other2_Revenue
```

I know the line that is causing the issue, but I do not know how to resolve it...

```
SUM((f.Other1_Revenue + f.Other2_Revenue) / (CW.MRR_Goal)) AS 'Total'
```

What I am trying to do is get the percentage of the goal but I cant get past the division to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your divisor with `nullif(Divisor, 0)` to avoid divide by zero exceptions. When `Divisor` is `0` we'll use `null` instead and the entire expression will evaluate to `null`, our nearest analogue for [`undefined`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_%28mathematics%29#Undefined_operations_in_arithmetic) in SQL.

```
select
 o.*
,Numerator / nullif(o.Divisor, 0) as Quotient
from (values -- sample values
     (1.0, 0)
    ,(2.0, 1)
    ,(3.0, 2)
) as o(Numerator, Divisor)
order by
 o.Numerator;
```

Output:

| Numerator | Divisor | Quotient |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 0 | NULL |
| 2.0 | 1 | 2.0 |
| 3.0 | 2 | 1.5 |

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. You don't want to represent div by 0s as 0 because that doesn't make any sense. Null is as close to undefined as it gets.

Comment: @Brad if you speak about "things that makes sense", it could be argued that this way doesn't make sense either, as it changes `x / 0` to `x / NULL` so it is considering that `0 = NULL`. It is indeed a clearer and shorter way programatically speaking, but is not accurate mathematically speaking. Either way, I agree that `NULL` is the closest representation of an undefined math value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `IIF`:

```
SUM(IIF(CW.MRR_Goal = 0, 0, (f.Other1_Revenue + f.Other2_Revenue) / (CW.MRR_Goal))
```

This way if the goal is equal to 0 then it will `SUM` the 0 rather than trying the division whereas if the goal is not equal to 0 then it will do the division.

More on `IIF` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213574.aspx

As [user3540365](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3540365/user3540365) mentioned `IIF` only applies from SQL Server 2012 as opposed to CASE which applies from SQL Server 2008 onwards see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) and is an SQL standard.

Comment: mention `SQL Server 2012`

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` statement:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN CW.MRR_Goal <> 0 THEN (f.Other1_Revenue + f.Other2_Revenue)/(CW.MRR_Goal) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total'
```

This way, it will perform the division only if the value of `CW.MRR_Goal` in that record is other than zero; if it's zero, it will return 0

Comment: IIF was added to SQL Server in 2012 - CASE has been around forever. You may want to explore how to use begin try/begin catch which would handle (unanticipated) problems gracefully.